# can't debug in VS Code after reinstalling VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had to reinstall VS Code for some issues I had and now I can't debug any application. Neither existing ones nor new ones, including a simple console app.

My environment is windows 10 and windows server 2019.  The issue happens in both machines.

I have Visual Studio 2022 (to compile 4.7.2 applications) side-by-side with VS Code (8.0.100).

I'm using the zip version of VS Code v 1.84.2

In VS Code I installed "manually a few plug-ins" since I'm in an isolated network.  No Internet access.  The plug_in are

- net install toll v 2.0.0
- C# v 2.14.8
- C# Dev Kit v 1.2.5
- Intellicode for C# 0.1.26
- rest client v 0.25.1

"dotnet --version" returns 8.0.100

I'm able to run "dotnet build" and "dotnet run"

In one my most complicated projects (netcore webapi) I have logging implemented throughout out the code and I see the code running.  I can also call the APIs and they returned the expected results.

The only thing I can't do is debug.

When I try to debug I get "No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# in order to debug"

In addition, towards the bottom of the screen, while trying to debug I see a message "Error acquiring .NET!"

One side note is that VS Code "explorer" does not display "solution explorer" any longer. For both existing projects as well as new projects.

All this used to work until I reinstall VS Code.

I looked at a lot of articles on the net and nothing help me so far.  Does anybody has any ideas?

Thanks in advance!